# Issue with Snippet

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

> This question can be closed and deleted. I made a stupid mistake! `:P`

I have this snippet in my answer here: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34833630/462627):

```css
* {font-family: Segoe UI;}
#console {position: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; height: 100px; overflow: auto; font-family: consolas; background: #ccc; border-top: 1px solid #999; margin: 0; font-size: 10pt;}
#console strong:first-child {background: #eee; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; display: block; padding: 3px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="disp"><input type="submit" value="Calc" id="sub" />
<pre id="console"><strong>Console:<strong></pre>
```

This is how it displays:

[image]

Something's wrong with the borders, but if we inspect the snippet, it generates so many unnecessary tags, like nested `<strong>`:

[image]

Why is it so? It happens even in the above one. I am using Google Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<strong>Console:<strong>
```

It should be

```
<strong>Console:</strong>
```

So everything works fine.

Comment: Sheeeeeeeeeesh!!!

Comment: How long did you take to find out that stupid mistake of mine? `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar, less than a minute - just read the code and looked at screenshot. Even without opening the answer.

Comment: You are great. Ha ha.